# Do we need separate tags for [habitable-zone] and [goldilocks-zone]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, specific-tag

We have separate tags for [habitable-zone](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/habitable-zone) and [goldilocks-zone](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/goldilocks-zone) — does it make sense to keep both of these?

Of the two, [habitable-zone](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/habitable-zone) appears to be used more frequently, although its tag wiki entry does define it in terms of a "Goldilocks Zone".

Comment: Done with the merge!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on a quick Google search, they do appear to be completely synonymous. I think we should prefer [habitable-zone](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/habitable-zone) as the main tag and make [goldilocks-zone](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/goldilocks-zone) a synonym, because "habitable" is a more plain rendering of the concept whereas "goldilocks" requires an understanding of the British fairy tale and how the parallel is drawn ("not too hot" and "not too cold").